# require value and respective key from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, min

I have a a array like below and i want min value and it's index for searching tax class id

```
Array
(
    [tax_class_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 13
        )
    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6233
            [1] => 3195
            [2] => 19192
        )

)
```

and i am searching least price and respective key in tax_class_id. In this Senario, i require lowest in price i.e 3195 and tax_id - 13 i.e key [1]

My Code is

```
$prod_total = array();
for($i = 1;$i <= $chunk;$i++){ 
    if($i == 1) {
        $min_product_amt = min($product_amt['price']);
        $index = array_search($min_product_amt, $product_amt);

        $product_total =  $min_product_amt; 
        //ceil Round numbers up to the nearest integer 
        $prod_total['price'] = ceil($product_total * $discount/100);
        $prod_total['tax_id'] = $product_amt['tax_class_id'];
        //Remove the first element from an array
        array_shift($product_amt['price']); 
        array_shift($product_amt['tax_class_id']);          
    } else { 
        $second_min_product_amt = min($product_amt['price']);
        $index = array_search($min_product_amt, $product_amt);

        $product_total = $second_min_product_amt;
        $prod_total['price'] = ceil($product_total * $discount/100);
        $prod_total['tax_id'] = $product_amt['tax_class_id'];
        array_shift($product_amt['price']); 
        array_shift($product_amt['tax_class_id']);              
    }
}
print_r($prod_total);
    die;
```

Comment: Can you show what output you need?

Comment: How about starting with an actual question / problem statement?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Your question appears to be about min value and index but I cannot see issues in your code...

Comment: @rajkumar none of the answers suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=Array
(
    'tax_class_id' => Array
    (
        0 => 12,
            1 => 13,
            2 => 13
        ),
    'price' => Array
(
    0 => 6233,
            1 => 3195,
            2 => 19192
        )

);

$minValue= min($array['price']);
$minKey=array_keys($array['price'], $minValue);
$tax_id=$array['tax_class_id'][$minKey[0]];
echo $tax_id;
```

This code will work for your issue. First i get the minimum value of nested array `price` and then it's associated `key`. After that i just access the nested array `tax_class_id` and get the value of the field i need like accessing every array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
    "tax_class_id" => [
        12,
        13,
        13
    ],
    "price" => [
        6233,
        3195,
        19192
    ]
];

$lowestFound;
foreach($data["price"] as $i => $price){
    if(!$lowestFound || $lowestFound[1] > $price)
        $lowestFound = [$i,$price];
}
echo $data["tax_class_id"][$lowestFound[0]];
```

This code get tax_class_id of lowest price key in one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think array_column gives you a nice output.

```
$array=Array
(
'tax_class_id' => Array(
        0 => 12,
        1 => 13,
        2 => 13
    ),
'price' => Array(
        0 => 6233,
        1 => 3195,
        2 => 19192
    )

);
// Find minimum value
$min= min($array['price']);
// Find key of min value
$Key=array_search($min, $array['price']);
// Extract all values with key[min value]
$new = array_column($array, $Key);
Var_dump($new);
```

The output in $new will now be

```
array(2) {
     [0]=> int(13)
     [1]=> int(3195)
}
```

Basically both of the values you are looking for.
https://3v4l.org/NsdiS